# How to not restore GIT submodules using DotNetCoreCLI@2

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I'm using DotNetCoreCLI@2 restore in a build pipeline in ADO, and am not finding a way to keep it from checking out submodules.  There is an authentication issue so I'm using a Powershell script to do so successfully, but that restore command causes the build to fail.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2 
  displayName: "Restore"
  inputs:
    command: restore
    selectOrConfig: config
    nugetConfigPath: nuget.config
    workingDirectory: ..
    verbosityRestore: Normal
```

There appears to be a restoreArguments input shown at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines, however there is no explanation of thus property's possible values.

Comment: I have feeling that you are mixing two things here. Git submodules are checked out on pre-initialization. It doesn't actually relate to restore. Restore step restores nuget packages based on configuration or description in .csproj. If you have problems with authorization for some private feeds then you cannot correctly restore packages.

Comment: Thank you.  You are correct.  I guess constantly context switching when debugging doesn't help.  :s

Answer (score 1):

To check out submodules, you can add the Checkout step with the `submodules: true`. For more details and alternative option, please refer [Submodules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#submodules).

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: true
```

About the authentication issue in restore step, you can add a [NuGetAuthenticate@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-authenticate-v1?view=azure-pipelines) task before the restore task.